# Resizing font with animation, jquery

Tags: jquery, html, fonts, jquery-animate

As you read the `title` of this problem you already know what i want to do.
I've read something about that `resizing with animation` but cant accelerate the solutions with my problem. If u have time to check my code:

These are the buttons that i use for the whole functionality.
Id for the text that need to be resized is ("fontce").

`<form id="forma">
        <p>Големина на фонт</p>
        <button type="button" value="Pocetna" onclick="Pocetna()">Почетна</button>
        <button type="button" value="Zgolemi" onclick="Zgolemi()">Зголеми</button>
        <button type="button" value="Namali" onclick="Namali()">Намали</button>
    </form>`

This function i want to bring the font to the normal.

```
var s = $("#fontce").css('fontSize');
function Pocetna() {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            ("#fontce").animate({
            "fontSize":s
            },1000);
        });
```

And the function to make the font bigger:

```
function Zgolemi()
    {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            var s1 = $(this.fontSize);
            ("#fontce").animate({
               "fontSize":s1*1.5
            },1000);
        })
    }
```

The function for making the font smaller is opposite of the upper one.

Comment: your `var s = $("#fontce").css('fontSize')` is `16px` but `.animate({
               "fontSize":` maybe need integer value .

Comment: @Smollet777 you have right i fixed that using parseInt (dont know does it work like that ) but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let s = $("#fontce").css('fontSize').slice(0, -2);

$("#pocetna").click(Pocetna);
$("#zgolemi").click(Zgolemi);
$("#namali").click(Namali);

function Pocetna() {
  $("#fontce").animate({
    fontSize: s
  }, 1000);
}

function Zgolemi() {
  let s1 = $("#fontce").css('fontSize').slice(0, -2);
  console.log(s1)
  $("#fontce").animate({
    fontSize: s1 * 1.5
  }, 1000);
}

function Namali() {
  let s2 = $("#fontce").css('fontSize').slice(0, -2);
  console.log(s2)
  $("#fontce").animate({
    fontSize: s2 / 1.5
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="forma">
    <p>Големина на фонт</p>
    <button type="button" value="Pocetna" id="pocetna">Почетна</button>
    <button type="button" value="Zgolemi" id="zgolemi">Зголеми</button>
    <button type="button" value="Namali" id="namali">Намали</button>
</form>
<p id="fontce">
    To connect to the internet, you'll need an Internet service provider (ISP)
    and some hardware:ISP. An ISP is a company that gives you access to the Internet.
    You sign up for an account with an ISP just as you do for telephone service or utilities.
    ISPs are usually phone companies( for a DSL or fiber optic connection)
    or TV providers(for cable or satellite connection).<br>
    Hardware. For a broadband connection, such as DSL, fiber optic, or cable,
    you'll need a boradband modem. This might be included as part of the start-up hardware from your ISP
    wgen you sign up for a broadband account. If you play to share Internet access with multiple PCs by
    using a home network, you'll also need a router.
</p>
```

Comment: Everything is fine except the method Pocetna() that returns the font back to the normal.

Comment: @VL4DiMiRG and it must do what?

Comment: bring the font to the normal.. the default font size is 16px.. and when u press that button it brings the font size to 16px.. i found the solution its a bit complex maybe that i dont understand all things as it need to be.. but its fine.. tnx for help and idea with slice